# RichTextBox in WPF does not have an property as .Lines?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

is there an equivalent to [.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) of winForms in WPF?

I'm using this currently:

```
var textRange = new TextRange(TextInput.Document.ContentStart, TextInput.Document.ContentEnd);
string[] lines = textRange.Text.Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RichTextBox is a FlowDocument type and that does not have a Lines property.  What you are doing seems like a good solution.  You may want to use [IndexOf](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/312312/Counting-lines-in-a-string) instead of split.

You can also add an extension method like the article suggests:

```
public static long Lines(this string s)
{
    long count = 1;
    int position = 0;
    while ((position = s.IndexOf('\n', position)) != -1)
        {
        count++;
        position++;         // Skip this occurance!
        }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm very late to the party, but I came up with another **reliable and reusable** solution using RTF parsing.

---

## Idea

In RTF, every paragraph ends with a `\par`. So e.g. if you enter this text

```
Lorem ipsum
Foo
Bar
```

in a `RichTextBox`, it will internally be stored as (very very simplified)

```
\par
Lorem ipsum\par
Foo\par
Bar\par
```

therefore, it is a quite reliable method to simply count the occurrences of those `\par` commands. Note though that there is always 1 more `\par` than there are actual lines.

---

## Usage

Thanks to [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), my proposed solution can simply be used like this:

```
int lines = myRichTextBox.GetLineCount();
```

where `myRichTextBox` is an instance of the [`RichTexBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

---

## Code

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the <see cref="RichTextBox"/> as the actual RTF.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetAsRTF(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            textRange.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the <see cref="RichTextBox"/> as plain text only.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetAsText(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        return new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of lines in the <see cref="RichTextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static int GetLineCount(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        // Idea: Every paragraph in a RichTextBox ends with a \par.

        // Special handling for empty RichTextBoxes, because while there is
        // a \par, there is no line in the strict sense yet.
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextBox.GetAsText()))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // Simply count the occurrences of \par to get the number of lines.
        // Subtract 1 from the actual count because the first \par is not
        // actually a line for reasons explained above.
        return Regex.Matches(richTextBox.GetAsRTF(), Regex.Escape(@"\par")).Count - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int lines = MainTbox.Document.Blocks.Count;
```

it is as simple is this.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22618730)